# Why am I able to print this field in a static method?

Tags: java, eclipse, anonymous-class

```
public class Main {
    private final int value = 3;

    public static Runnable buildRunner() {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Main.this.value);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler, with JRE 7.

In the `buildRunner` method - why I am able to see the `this` of Main? What is the 'this' of Main in a static method? Why does this compile?

I can only do that if `value` is final. I cannot call instance methods of Main and stuff, but value is not decalred `static`! Furthermore, if I want to use in the `buildRunner` method, outside the `run` method of the `new Runnable`, the compiler stops me from doing that.

Comment: Are you sure this exact code compiles ? javac will not compile it (Main.java:9: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context)

Comment: The code in not valid. Looks like a bug in Eclipse compiler.

Comment: You aren't. This won't even compile.

Comment: using this inside run method is pointing to the Runnable object

Comment: This code is invalid. There is no way you can use `Main.this.value` like that inside a static method.

Comment: Eclipse not just compiles this, it succesfully runs it and prints out 3 (when I do Main.buildRunner().run()). Javac however does not compile this indeed. Didn't figure it would be a JDT compiler bug.

Comment: Soooo... Who wants to submit a bug report?

Comment: The same thing happens in Eclipse Indigo. It runs without errors and prints "3"

Comment: @George If you (or anyone else) submit a bug report, mind sharing a link?

Comment: report for the bug and change the final keyword of value var to static

Comment: @user3580294 Bug reported at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438890

Comment: @George It's good to report it for completeness' sake, but I wouldn't expect a fix quickly or even at all, as the issue is obscure and mostly harmless.

Comment: @Boann you are correct. However, I did my duty and it made me feel good : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JLS § 15.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) says "The value of an expression of the form `TypeName.this` is the *n*'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`". Since there is no *enclosing instance* of Main in your example, the code is not valid.

In javac, the code produces the error "non-static variable `this` cannot be referenced from a static context". The fact that it compiles in Eclipse appears to be an obscure bug in Eclipse (which has its own compiler).

Comment: It does not just comple. It *runs* and prints out 3.

Comment: @George Just a bad optimization that incorrectly replaces inaccessible final field with a compile-time constant.

Comment: @George - That makes no sense. Fix your code so that it can compile from the command line. Then run it, and if there are any errors, then you can come back to ask a valid question. I would strongly suggest you get used to compile from the command line. The command line never lies ;)

Comment: Other than that, Boann's post should be accepted as an answer (since it does answer why your code "sees" the `this` reference from the static method).

Comment: So then it's not from an optimization and instead a bug? It seems like the optimization would be considered after the reason you gave. To be clear, this code wouldn't work, as it does for me, at any other time/machine expect development under eclipse?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It's a bug, although it might have been caused by an optimization attempt. If it were intended to work, then `Main.this.value` should also be readable from within a static method of `Main` *without* wrapping the expression in an inner `Runnable`, but if you try that, then Eclipse says: "Cannot use `this` in static context".